# Get JSONObject with ID in Android

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to read my data from my localhost to Android Studio. I have used volley to do this. I'm having issue getting the values from my json. Here's my json.

```
{"studentList":[{"username":"2011089882","password":"","section":"c4a","year":"4th"}]}
```

Here's my code in Android.

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(urlJsonObj, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

            try {
                String username = response.getString("username");
                String section = response.getString("section");
                String year = response.getString("year");

                jsonResponse = "";
                jsonResponse += "Username: " + username + "\n\n";
                jsonResponse += "Section: " + section + "\n\n";
                jsonResponse += "Year: " + year + "\n\n\n";

                txtView.setText(jsonResponse);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            hidepDialog();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
}
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    JSONArray parentArray = response.getJSONArray("studentList");
    if (parentArray.length() == 0) {
        //no students
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String username = finalObject.getString("username");
            String password = finalObject.getString("password");
            String section = finalObject.getString("section");
            String year = finalObject.getString("year");
        }
    }
```

this will loop through every student in "studentList"

make sure to import JSONArray`import org.json.JSONArray;`

Comment: I'm getting error with "JSONArray parentArray = response.getJSONArray("studentList");". It is looking for integer parameter..

Comment: No problem! Make sure to handle the case where if the array returns 0 students. Eg. `txtView.setText("No students found.");`

Answer (score 0):

```
{"studentList":[{"username":"2011089882","password":"","section":"c4a","year":"4th"}]}
```

Structure of your JSON response is an Object containing a list, which contains an object of type student
which contains username & password, where as you are directly trying to get username from outer object.

`String username = response.getString("username");`

Firstly You need to extract Object from List then access username.

```
JsonArray jsonArr = response.getJSONArray("studentList");
JsonObject studentObj = jsonArr.get(0);
```

Comment: Thanks.. Can you help me how to extract Object from list? Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: you can also loop Array if you want to extract all Students

Answer (score 0):

```
 try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("studentList");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String username = jsonObject1.getString("username");
        String section = jsonObject1.getString("section");
        String year = jsonObject1.getString("year");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, username + " " + section + " " + year, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope this helps